# What is this plant with flowers in subtle shades of red?

Tags: identification, flowers

I noticed this plant in a public area:

[image]

There were several specimen. Most are red-flowered:

[image]

Digital photography and monitors can't reproduce the exact color, but in nature it is red 'carmin rouge':

[image]

Some of them are of lighter red:

[image]

[image]

Almost pink:

[image]

Leaf:

[image]

I know it is a known plant, but I don't know its name. What about you?

Comment: Can you tell us where you live, or at least where you found this plant? Thanks!

Comment: Where I live is visible in my profile, and where I found the plant is described in the question,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're Salvia splendens, a tender perennial usually grown as an  annual in summer bedding displays in temperate zones. These are past their best; the 'subtle shades of red' are just because they're  fading as they're coming to an end, which is not surprising given the time of year;  info and image showing them at their best here  https://www.thespruce.com/red-salvia-scarlet-sage-salvia-splendens-2132144. You will note from the link there are other colours of Salvia splendens available - quite which these were originally is next to impossible to say, given they're coming to the end of their life and fading. There is a named variety 'Vanguard' which has dark sludgy pink flowers, but I don't know other varietal names - it might be possible, if you google S. splendens varieties, to ascertain particular names of different colour varieties, but not sure how helpful that would be at this stage.

The scarlet colour ones were much used in the UK years ago as part of many Borough summer flower displays in parks and public gardens.

Comment: No, the color is not fading. There are several plants, and each has its own color throughout the year. If Salvia splendens has only one color, this is not Salvia spledens.

Comment: Well, you don't have to agree with me, that's up to you, but I don't doubt the accuracy  of my answer, so won't be altering it. These will all be dead in the next 4 weeks, unless where you live doesn't get below 5 deg C

Comment: There is a cultivar called Salvia splendens 'vanguard' which is a slightly different shade of flower, but they're still Salvia splendens, and 'vanguard' doesn't look like these either - but then they wouldn't, at this time of year

Comment: It is not a matter of agreeing or disagreeing. :) Also, I am not asking you to change your answer, I just cĺaim that something must be false in your answer.

Comment: As I said, that's your privilege, I don't really know what else you want me to say.

Comment: Bamboo is right (as always) it is definitely salvia splendens.  There are numerous colors available.  In the second to last photo, your plant does look like it is fading

Comment: @TylerK. But bamboo says it is just the same red but fading.

Comment: @VividD I wouldn't say they are fading, as Tyler K and Bamboo mildly say. To me, some of them already look half wilted and the red pigment degraded.

Comment: The point is, the difference in flower color (there are three colors) is not a consequence of fading, as bamboo says in the answer. There are three colors, all close to red, at any given moment of the year.

Comment: @VividD You certainly know better because you have seen them in reality, but for me, seeing only the pictures, they look like one colour in different stages. That's why I set a bounty: even if they are different colours by default, they are still Salvia splendens, only uncommon cultivars. If you want to know the name of the cultivar, ping me in chat and I'll try to find out using non-gardening methods.

Comment: @Alina - the link I provided in the answer above says they come in other colours, and lists  the colours available, but doesn't give a varietal name for each. The only other colour variety I know about with a name is 'vanguard' also mentioned in a comment above. Some research through Google should reveal varietal names, but Vivid should be able to do that I'd have thought, now the name of the plant is known